# How do i invoke the signalr connection.on from the controllers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using the SQL service broker to send notifications from the ms SQL database to the controller when there is a change. It triggers fine. I set up a console.wrtieline to see if it triggers and it does get triggered when the database has a change. But What I'm trying to do is when there's a database change I want this to get fired off `await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DatabaseChanged", "it changed");` However, when I do use that nothing happens. Then I tried to create an object from the DatabaseHub. Unfortunately, I can't do that. It just gives me System null errors. I also tried to take out _hubContext out from the `listener.TableChanged` into the Account method and nothing gets called either. How do I call the javascript on function from the controller?

controller:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _UM;
        private readonly FlubrContext _FC;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        private readonly IHubContext<DatabaseHub> _hubContext;

        public ProfileController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> UM, FlubrContext FC, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHubContext<DatabaseHub> hubContext)
        {
            _UM = UM;
            _FC = FC;
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Account(string id)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DatabaseChanged", "it changed");
            ViewBag.change = "hey";
            var connection = "Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=Flubr;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(connection, "Flubr", "UserMessage");
            listener.TableChanged += async (o, e) => {
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DatabaseChanged", "it changed");
                Console.WriteLine("it changed");

            };
            listener.Start();
         }
      }
```

javascript:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script>
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/databaseHub")
            .build();

        connection.on("DatabaseChanged", (message) => {
            alert(message)
            console.log(message)
        });

        connection.start().catch((err) => console.error(err.toString()));
    </script>
}
```

hub:

```
namespace Flubr
{
    public class DatabaseHub: Hub
    {

      
    }
}
```

start up class

```
using Flubr.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Flubr.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flubr
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<FlubrContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FlubrContextConnection")));
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {

                o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

            });
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {

                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;

            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSingleton<SignalHub>();
            services.AddSingleton<DatabaseHub>();
            services.AddScoped<MessagesRepository>();


        }




            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseBrowserLink();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                    app.UseHsts();
                }
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseAuthentication();

                app.UseAuthorization();



                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapHub<SignalHub>("/SignalHub");
                    endpoints.MapHub<SignalHub>("/DatabaseHub");
                });

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you confident the connection is being properly established? Can you check the browser debugger to see if anything is getting sent down to the browser at all? (Network Tab - Filter by WS and look at the Messages)

Comment: `endpoints.MapHub<SignalHub>("/DatabaseHub");` should be `endpoints.MapHub<DatabaseHub>("/DatabaseHub");`. Also you don't have to call `services.AddSingleton<SignalHub>();` or `services.AddSingleton<DatabaseHub>();`.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos fixing the mistake with the endpoints worked, i'm receiving the message now. I dont need `services.AddScoped<DatabaseHub>();` but i do need `services.AddSingleton<SignalHub>();` or im going to get the error `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Name.SignalHub' while attempting to activate 'Name.Controllers.HomeController'.`